# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component error when using custom hook action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-thunk

so I have this custom hook action that calls my custom fetch wrapper and stores the data in redux store on success. I only return back the loading state so that I can have local loading for my components.

The problem I'm facing right now is I'm getting this error in the logs albeit the functionality I need is working.

Error: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Custom Hook Action with useEffect:

```
const usefooBar = (idOne: number, idTwo: number, limit: number): Thunk => (dispatch) :[{loading: boolean}] => {
        const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
        const endpoint = getEndpoints().fooBar;

        const body : FooBarRequest = {
            idOne:  idOne,
            idTwo: idTwo,
            limit: limit
        };

        useEffect(() => {
            performStandardRequest({
                url: endpoint,
                body,
                method: "POST",
                success: (r) =>
                {
                    setLoading(false);
                    dispatch(fooBarAction.fetchfooBarSuccess({idOne:  idOne, fooBar: r.payload }))
                },
                failure: () => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    dispatch(displayGenericNetworkError());
                },
                request: () => {
                    setLoading(true);
                    dispatch(fooBarAction.fetchfooBarRequest(body))
                },
                dispatch
            });
        },[idOne, idTwo, limit]);
        return [{loading}]
};

export const fooBarAction = {
    fetchfooBarRequest: typesafeActionCreator<FooBarRequest>(FETCH_FOO_BAR_REQUEST),
    fetchfooBarSuccess: typesafeActionCreator<fooBarPerFoo>(FETCH_FOO_BAR_SUCCESS),
    fetchfooBarFailed: voidTypesafeActionCreator(FETCH_FOO_BAR_FAILED),
    usefooBar
};
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please also share the component from where you are using this custom hook